# "Run-time error '1004' - couldn't find file"

Tags: vba, excel, runtime, runtime-error

I am running a VBA script that mass converts dbf files to an excel spreadsheet. I have used this script a couple times earlier this week, and it worked perfectly.

However, I tried using it again for some new data, and I am running into the error listed in the title: "Sorry we couldn't find *file*.dbf, is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted?"

Frustratingly, when I go back to the older modules that worked for previous data, it no longer works! Nothing has changed in the code, so I am quite confused. Here it is"

```
Sub OpenDBF()

Folder = "C:\Users\Smiliepants101\Documents\Brown\Thesis\CatAg\"

FName = Dir(Folder & "*.dbf")

Do While FName <> ""
    Set bk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName)
    bk.Close savechanges:=True

    FName = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FName = Dir(Folder & "*.dbf")
```

`FName` is only the file *name*, not the full path.  Your code will work if `Folder` happens to be the current directory, but will likely fail if it isn't.

Instead of this:

```
Set bk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName)
```

Do this instead:

```
Set bk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folder & FName)
```